# Render an static partial through .ajax in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

So, I have 2 follow/unfollow forms in my Rails code. Which are like this

```
<%= form_tag( {:controller => 'profile', :action => 'unfollow_topic' }) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :topic_id, @topic.id %>
  <button class="question_button" type="submit">Unfollow</button>
<% end %>
```

and this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'profile', :action => 'follow_topic' }) do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :topic_id, @topic.id %>
 <button class="question_button" type="submit">Follow</button>
<% end %>
```

And then I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#follow form').submit(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response){ $('#follow').html(response); }
      });
    return false;
    });
  });   
</script>
```

My question is how i can return from my controller the appropriate "follow/unfollow" partial for it to be replaced with the response returned.

What I currently have is this, but it doesn't seems to work:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to('/' + topic.type + '/' + topic.uri) }
    format.js   { render :partial => 'unfollow_topic' }
  end
```

But instead if renders the whole page, I believe it's actually responding to the format.html and not the format.js any ideas?

Comment: what is in your '_unfollow_topic.js.erb' file?  Have you tried stripping everything out of their and just putting an some alert javascript? `alert("Hello!");`  That might tell you if you are even getting your partial back.

Comment: ajax requests are usually used to update part of the page As I've understood from your question you want to update whole page with ajax request Is it correct?

Comment: also please post a chunk of your log with this request

Comment: @ipd Yes, I've tried to put an alert on the success stament and I do get a response back. Also, I don't have a _unfllow_topic.js.erb file, should I have it? Wasn't RJS deprecated with rails 3?

Comment: It will look for that partial, try creating that partial and putting the alert in there and see what you get.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#follow form').submit(function(e) {
          $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'html'
            success: function(response){ $('#follow').html(response); }
          });
        return false;
        });
      });   
    </script>
```

controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html  do
      if request.xhr?
        render :partial => 'unfollow_topic'
      else
        redirect_to('/' + topic.type + '/' + topic.uri)
      end
    end
end
```